# How Do You Continue Unitl A Break Is Hit Using Assembly In GDB?

Tags: gdb

I have used GDB in the past, but this is my first time really using it for assembly debugging. All I know is how to load up the program, step through instructions (stepi), pass over functions (i.e. nexti), and set breakpoints (break *).

What I really would like to know is if there is a way to continue until my next break point is hit kind of like continue in the standard mode? I looked a few places and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: what's wrong with the standard `continue`?

Comment: I set a break point at an memory address 2 assembly instructions away and hit continue and the program ran to completion. (i.e. break *<address 2i away> continue). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Oh my gosh! Just realized there was a branch instruction, so that break never got reached. I feel silly now

Comment: Should I post an answer for that or just let the question be?

Comment: now I set the right breakpoint, but after a continue I get 'Cannot access memory at addres <address>' and it won't let me step to the next instruction now.